# Javascript input returns NaN or undefiend

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a tip calculator and I would like the tip amount to display for the user to see. The problem I'm having is the output showing up as 'NaN' or 'undefined'. I've tried making changes to my code but I keep getting the same result.

```js
function calculateTip() {
  var billInput = document.getElementById('bill');
  var tipPercentage = document.getElementById('tip');
  var tipPercentageCalc = (tipPercentage / 100);
  var tipAmount = (bill * tipPercentageCalc).toFixed(2);
  tipAmount = tipAmount.toString();
  document.getElementById('display_text').innerHTML = 'Tip = $', +tipAmount;

};
```

```html
<div id='calculate'>
  <p>Bill: $<input id="bill" type="number" name="bill" placeholder="Enter bill amount" onchange="calculateTip()"></p>
  <p>Tip: %<input id="tip" type="number" name="tip" placeholder="15%" onchange="calculateTip()"></p>
  <input type="button" name="submit" onclick="calculateTip();">
</div>
<div id="display">
  <h4 id="display_text"></h4>
</div>
```

Comment: The answers below will help, just a suggestion though in the future, part of the fun of programming is the art of debugging your own code. Making changes isn't so much debugging as it is trial and error. Try inserting debuggers and/or breakpoints next time and stepping through line by line, and really think about what is going on in each line.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to get the value of your fields. Because without the property `.value`, it returns `HTMLObject`.

```
function calculateTip() {
    var billInput = parseFloat(document.getElementById('bill').value);
    var tipPercentage = parseFloat(document.getElementById('tip').value);
    var tipPercentageCalc = (tipPercentage / 100);
    var tipAmount = (bill * tipPercentageCalc).toFixed(2);
    tipAmount = tipAmount.toString();
    document.getElementById('display_text').innerHTML = 'Tip = $', + tipAmount;

};
```

Comment: You'll also want to use `parseFloat()` to convert the string to a number.

Answer (score 2):

You are reading `billInput` and `tipPercentage` as **HTML element objects** instead of the text the user types into them, which will be their `.value` properties.

Answer (score 0):

You're loading the element instead of the element value when declaring the variables `billInput` and `tipPercentage`. Try with this code:

```
var billInput = document.getElementById('bill').value;
var tipPercentage = document.getElementById('tip').value;
```

Comment: Providing some details of what was the mistake and what is fixed on the code provided helps easily evaluate the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculateTip() {
// get the VALUE property of the textbox elements
// parseInt will turn them into numbers if they're not already.
// if they are not numbers you cannot use them in math.

  var billInput = parseInt(document.getElementById('bill').value);
  var tipPercentage = parseInt(document.getElementById('tip').value);
  var tipPercentageCalc = (tipPercentage / 100);
  var tipAmount = (billInput * tipPercentageCalc);

// isNaN stands for "is Not a Number"
// this checks if tipAmount is not a number
// if it is not we simply set it to the number 0
if (isNaN(tipAmount)) {
    tipAmount = 0;
  }

  // when you concatenate a number to a string you do not need to turn it into a string.
  // it will automatically be converted
  document.getElementById('display_text').innerHTML = 'Tip = $' + tipAmount;

};
```

```js
function calculateTip() {
// get the VALUE property of the textbox elements
// parseInt will turn them into numbers if they're not already.
// if they are not numbers you cannot use them in math.

  var billInput = parseInt(document.getElementById('bill').value);
  var tipPercentage = parseInt(document.getElementById('tip').value);
  var tipPercentageCalc = (tipPercentage / 100);
  var tipAmount = (billInput * tipPercentageCalc);

// isNaN stands for "is Not a Number"
// this checks if tipAmount is not a number
// if it is not we simply set it to the number 0
if (isNaN(tipAmount)) {
    tipAmount = 0;
  }
  
  // when you concatenate a number to a string you do not need to turn it into a string.
  // it will automatically be converted
  document.getElementById('display_text').innerHTML = 'Tip = $' + tipAmount;

};
```

```html
<div id='calculate'>
  <p>Bill: $<input id="bill" type="number" name="bill" placeholder="Enter bill amount" onchange="calculateTip()"></p>
  <p>Tip: %<input id="tip" type="number" name="tip" placeholder="15%" onchange="calculateTip()"></p>
  <input type="button" name="submit" onclick="calculateTip();">
</div>
<div id="display">
  <h4 id="display_text"></h4>
</div>
```